# Duplicate words in a list

Tags: python, list, function

How can I return a duplicated word in a list?

I was asked to create a function, `word_count(text, n)`. The text is converted into a list and then return the word that is repeated n times. I've tried to write it but it seems to return every single word.

```
>>> repeat_word_count("one one was a racehorse two two was one too", 3)
['one']
```

I've used the for loop and conditioned it. I'm wanted to post my code but I'm scared that my school will find the code online :(

Comment: show your attempt and sample input your output and expected output

Comment: Your school must have given you course materials. Which part don't you understand? Do you have a tutor? If there is no-one to help you it's fair enough to ask for help on-line.

Comment: SO start doing homeworks....

Comment: Just a clue, create a case insensitive dictionary, split the text into words and add them to that dictionary.

Comment: If you already know how to split your text into a list of words, take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and you're almost done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what it is that you are wanting to do and without seeing your code I can't point out exactly where you're going wrong so I'll take you through creating this function step by step and you should be able to figure out where you went wrong.

I think you are trying to create this:

```
def function(a,b):
    """where a is a sentence and b is the target number. 
        The function will return to you each word in the 
        given sentence that occurs exactly b times."""
```

To do this we have to do the following:

- converts the sentence into a list of words and removes punctuation,capitalization,and spaces.
- iterates through each unique word in the sentence and print it if it occurs exactly ***b*** times in the sentence
- put these together to make a function

so in your example your sentence was "one one was a racehorse two two was one too", and you're looking for all words that occur exactly 3 times, so the function should return the word "one"

---

We'll look at each step one at a time.

FIRST STEP - 
we have to take the sentence or sentences and convert them into a list of words.  Since I don't know if you will be using sentences with punctuation and/or capitalization I'll have to assume that its possible and plan to deal with them.  We'll have to omit any punctuation/spaces from the list and also change all the letters in each word to lowercase if they happened to have a capital letter because even though "Cat" and "cat" are the same word, according to a computer brain, "Cat" does NOT equal any of these:

- "cat" - ***lowercase c doesn't match uppercase C in "Cat"***
- " Cat" - ***there is an extra space at the start of the word***
- "Cat." - ***There is a period after the word***
- "Cat " - ***There is a space after the word***

So if we use "One one was a racehorse two two was one, too." as our input we'll need to handle spaces, punctuation, and capitalization.  Luckily all of this work can be done with 2 lines of code by using a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/list-comprehension/info) to get rid of all the junk and create a list of words.

```
import re

wordlist=[i.lower() for i in re.findall(r"[\w']+",sentence)]
```

This gives us our list of words:

```
['one', 'one', 'was', 'a', 'racehorse', 'two', 'two', 'was', 'one', 'too']
```

---

SECOND STEP -
Now we need to iterate through each ***Unique*** word in the wordlist and see if it occurs exactly ***b*** times. Since we only need unique words we can create a list that only contains each word exactly once by converting the wordlist from a ***list*** to a ***set*** and looping through each word in the set and counting the number of times they appear in the wordlist.  Any that occur exactly ***b*** number of times are our solutions.  I'm not exactly sure how you were wanting the results returned but i'm going to assume you want to have each word that fits the criteria to be printed one at a time.

```
for word in set(wordlist):
    if wordlist.count(word)==b:
        print word
```

---

THIRD STEP -

Now I'll put all this together to create my function:

```
 import re

 def repeat_word_count(a,b):
     wordlist=[i.lower() for i in re.findall(r"[\w']+",a)]
     for word in set(wordlist):
         if wordlist.count(word)==b:
             print word
```

I hope this helps you understand a bit better